# Parse Time From NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get the time from a string that looks like `@"2016-05-12T16:25:55.000Z"`. I have tried something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.dateFormat       = @"HH:mm";
formatter.timeZone         = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSDate *serverDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSString* time = [formatter stringFromDate:serverDate];
NSLog(@"Time: %@", time);
```

But my `serverDate` is returning `null`. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an `NSDate` from an `NSString`, the date format has to completely match the entire string.

But it seems your goal is to get the time as a string. So just get the substring:

```
NSString *time = [dateString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(11, 5)];
```

Of course this doesn't deal with the timezone in any way. If you wish to parse the original string into an `NSDate` and then get the time from that date, all with needed timezone adjustments, then you need two date formats. One to parse the original string into an `NSDate`, and the 2nd (the one you already have), to generate the new string with the desired output (the time in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dateFormat property of your formatter to: `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`, and then get the time value using NSDateComponents.

Comment: Your format doesn't match the string in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your date to NSDate

```
+ (NSDate *) convertDateToNSDateWithGivenFormat: (NSString *) dateStr Format:(NSString*) format
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterDate = nil;
    NSDate *dateonly = nil;

    if (dateFormatterDate == nil) {
        dateFormatterDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatterDate setDateFormat:format];
    }
    dateonly = [dateFormatterDate dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dateStr]];

    return dateonly;
}
```

then use the NSDate variable to split date and time

```
+ (NSString *) GetFormattedTimeStringForGivenDate:(NSDate *) date
{
    NSString *retStr = nil;
    NSDate *now = date;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterDateOnly = nil;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterTimeOnly = nil;

    if (dateFormatterDateOnly == nil) {
        dateFormatterDateOnly = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatterDateOnly setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    }
    if (dateFormatterTimeOnly == nil) {
        dateFormatterTimeOnly = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatterTimeOnly setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss:a"];
    }
    //if you need date use this
    //retStr  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatterDateOnly stringFromDate:now]];
    retStr  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatterTimeOnly stringFromDate:now]];
    return retStr;
}
```

Here is example. You can change the Format as per your need:

```
   NSDate *myDt = [MyClass convertDateToNSDateWithGivenFormat: @"2016-05-12T16:25:55" Format:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *str = [MyClass GetFormattedTimeForGivenDate:myDt];
```